# Solr - Get 2 separate highlights on same field

Tags: solr, highlighting

We are using solr 4.9. We need different highlighting on same field on same time .

One highlight check for whole content and other check for only first N characters.

Please suggest how we can do this?? or if not possible then any alternative ways.

Thanks

Comment: Might be the simpliest way is to write your own highlighter implementation and enable it by `solrconfig.xml`. Are you familiar with Solr source code?

Comment: not much @Nikolay :(

Answer (score 0):

As a simpler solution, you can have one copy field that will copy only N chars from source to destination

```
<copyField source="cat" dest="text" maxChars="30000" />
```

Then while searching, you can specify both fields for highlighting

```
&hl=true&hl.fl=cat,text
```